# When I run a specific macro, I am able to run it most of the time but I often get a RunTime Error 1004. How can I make my macro more consistent?

Tags: excel, vba, runtime, xlsx

I have a macro that exports my tabs and saves them in specific folders as .xlsx documents. Typically the macro works, however it is becoming more and more inconsistent. When the macro fails to work, I receive the following error:

[Runtime Error 1004](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFrxp.png)

I was hoping to get some outside eyes to look at the macro and let me know if there is a way to make it operate consistently, as I am sure I am overlooking something somewhere.

This is my current macro:

```
Sub ExportSU400_XLSX()

Dim FPath As String
Dim xWs As Worksheet
Dim ArraySheet As Variant

Set ArraySheet = ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets

FPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False


For Each xWs In ArraySheet
                        xWs.Select
                        xWs.Copy
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:FilePath" & "\" & "File Name " & xWs.Name & Format(Now(), "_yyyy.mm.dd") & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=51
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
Next

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I have tried changing the FileFormat number to see if that worked. But I've otherwise been at a loss.

Comment: Does the worksheet name contain illegal characters for a filepath?

Comment: @BigBen No, the worksheet name is entirely text/numerical.

Comment: It should be `"C:\FilePath"`.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Good catch on that! The macro does include the \ - that was my error in copying and pasting into overstack.

Comment: Use `MsgBox "C:\FilePath" & "\" & "File Name " & xWs.Name & Format(Now(), "_yyyy.mm.dd") & ".xlsx"` to see if that's a 'reasonable' path. At the moment, it results in `C:\FilePath\File Name Sheet1_2024.02.21.xlsx` for `Sheet1`.

Comment: What's the purpose of `FPath`?  When it fails, what does the `SaveAs` path look like?

Comment: @TimWilliams This macro has been sort of frankensteined together from older macros, so the fpath may be entirely unnecessary. I don't know if I completely understand your second question as I am still learning VBA. When the macro fails, it doesn't save at all?

Comment: Same line as VBasic2008: is there some issue with the generated filename which is preventing it from saving? Does it always consistently fail on a given worksheet?  Maybe try commenting out the `DisplayAlerts` lines and see if you're missing any popups

Comment: Consider this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48507956/fileformat-51-or-52-doesnt-save-file-as-an-excel-file

Comment: @TimWilliams The MsgBox makes a viable pathway - it is the same nomenclature that has been working for over a year now, which is why I am so puzzled. I commented out the DisplayAlert lines however I only received the same 1004 error. The macro worked first thing this morning, however when I ran it again it error'd on the third worksheet. Now it gives an error on the first worksheet. The interesting thing is that the file does export and save, however it gives an error.

Comment: @user10186832 Thank you for the link. I removed the file extension and it totally removes the 1004 error, but it saves the file as a 21 file. Do you have any suggestions on how to get it to save as an .xlsx ?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28967762/getting-method-saveas-of-object-workbook-failed-error-while-trying-to-save-an

Comment: **UPDATE** - So, I tried directing the saveas file path to a local spot on my computer and it saved perfectly with no error. The file path I need it to go to is a folder on Sharepoint. I am thinking the problem lies somewhere with Sharepoint. Does anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: @SSlinky Thank you so much for that link. There is a lot of great information there that I have been using as trial and error. I now believe the issue lies somewhere with Sharepoint? Trying to explore that avenue now...